# standardized mean difference including between and within subject designs

Tags: r, repeated-measures, meta-analysis, cohens-d, forest-plot

I am in the process of drafting a meta-analysis for a research project. The document makes use of a forest plot (random-effects model) that depicts the standardized mean difference of each study along with the total effect of an intervention.

Most studies included in the analysis are between-subject (with an experimental and control group), and as such I can calculate the standardized mean difference between the experimental and control group quite easily. However, there are some within-subject designs (repeated measures pre- and post- intervention among the same participants) which I think would be great additions into the meta-analysis. I am unsure as to whether I can calculate the standardized mean difference for within-subject designs as I would for between subject designs, given that within-subject design would have a higher weight on the forest plot?

Alternatively, is there another way to compare the effect of an intervention while including data from both within- and between- subject designs?

Side note: I am using R (dmetar, metafor, meta packages) but am open to other recommendations.

Thank you for any responses!